# Redirect via JavaScript if Variable Equals False?

Tags: javascript

Ive tried just about everything I know how to do (not much tbh), so here is the code WITHOUT the attempted redirect:

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Locate position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition);
  } else {
    alert('It seems like Geolocation, which is required for this page, is not enabled in your browser. Please use a browser which supports it.');
  }
  blacklisted_areas = {
    'area 51': [1, 2],
    'pink unicorn zoo': [1, 2],
  };
  // Success callback function
  function displayPosition(pos) {
    var mylat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var mylong = pos.coords.longitude;
    var thediv = document.getElementById('locationinfo');
    thediv.innerHTML = '<p>Your longitude is :' + mylong + ' and your latitide is ' + mylat + '</p>';
  }
  var blacklisted = false;
  for (let x of Object.values(blacklisted_areas)) {
    if (displayPosition()[0] === x[0] && displayPosition()[1] === x[1]) {
        blacklisted = true;
    }
  }
  //Now right below here is where I need to check for blacklisted's value (if false redirect to a different site)
```

Please help me :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!blacklisted){
  window.location = "URL goes here";
}
```

This checks the opposite of blacklisted. If blacklisted is false, then the condition is true and the redirect happens.

Edit: navigator.geolocation is async, so you'll want to handle all your logic in the callback

```
function displayPosition(pos) {
  var mylat = pos.coords.latitude;
  var mylong = pos.coords.longitude;
  var thediv = document.getElementById('locationinfo');
  thediv.innerHTML = '<p>Your longitude is :' + mylong + ' and your latitide is ' + mylat + '</p>';

  var blacklisted = false;
  for (let x of Object.values(blacklisted_areas)) {
    if (mylat === x[0] && mylong === x[1]) {
      blacklisted = true;
    }
  }
  if(!blacklisted){
    window.location="insertURLHere";
  }
}
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Thank you, however is the current area where it is positioned not correct? please help with that as it does nothing.

Comment: navigator.geolocation is asynchronous. Try sticking everything from var blacklisted = false and below inside displayPosition()

Edit: Wait a sec, you'll have to reorganize quite a bit. Let me make a new comment after I think this through a bit

Comment: Not working, can you please more in detail where to put them? I get a Pos undefined error in console

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you SO much

Comment: I just edited my first response. Let me know if any part is unclear